# accessing a session in laravel with ionic framework

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a mobile app using Ionic framework, with Laravel in server side.
I have authenticated the user using the attempt method from Auth. Now I want all the HTTP requests to reach the session of the authenticated user.
Is there any session token or something to make it happen?

I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Satellizer project](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), it uses token based authentication, there is example for [ionic](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/ionic) in client side , and [laravel](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/php) for the server side